# Purple primer left on over night: can I use it?

Tags: pvc, primer, abs

I am using Oatey purple primer with Oatey medium gray pvc cement. This is a 2 inch PVC pipe job for pool pump to filter.

I have a joint where I applied purple primer then realized I am not ready for the fitting so I need to leave it overnight.  This fitting is to an ABS filter valve.  I realized I need Green ABS to PVC transition cement and will get some tomorrow.

Can I add some fresh primer on the PVC pipe before I glue it the next day with green PVC to ABS cement?  Or must I cut off that piece of pipe and start over?

Comment: you can use it now no need to cut it off. Most people don't let the primer dry prior to fitting the pieces. I thought PVC-ABS was for vent lines not pressure lines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, you can use it, just re-prime it.  You'll see that the fresh coat of primer with melt right through the dried primer.

Comment: How long can something that's primed sit before you should reapply primer?

Comment: @Mazura if it's still wet, you can use it. If it's dried, reapply.

Answer (score 2):

Oatey says the cement is to be applied while the primer is damp.

So, apply a small amount of new primer before gluing and glue after it has dried for a half a minute or so.

http://newsite.oatey.com/Channel/FAQ.html#Q08

Oatey says NOT to use primer on ABS only cleaner.

http://www.oatey.com/products/plastic-pipe-cements-and-primers/oatey-primers.